# Spring Boot @Autowired field return .NullPointerException (Using neo4J)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am making a small api using spring-boot and Neo4J, but for some reason the `@autowired` attributes to the domains are null in one of my `@Service` class. The automatically generated route correctly returns the nodes from Neo4J database, so I assume they must be some error in the beans connection

The controller :

```
@RestController
public class NodeController {
    @PostMapping("/metrics")
    public MetricJSON computeMetrics(
            @Valid @RequestBody MetricsPayload payload,
            @Autowired SocialNetwork socialNetwork
    ) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new MetricJSON(socialNetwork.fromRequest(payload));
    }
```

The `@Service` class

```
@Service
public class SocialNetwork  {
    @Autowired
    public NetworkRepository networkRepository;

    @Autowired
    public NodeRepository nodeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public Evolution evolution;

    public PersonalNetwork fromRequest(@NotNull MetricsPayload payload) throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Network network = this.networkRepository.findById(payload.getNetworkId()).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
        Node ego = this.nodeRepository.findByTag(payload.getEgoTag()).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
SimpleWeightedGraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> opn = this.nodeRepository.extractOPN(ego, payload.getDepth());
        return this.fromGraph(opn, ego, payload);
}
```

The Node domain class :

```
@org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Node("Node")
public class Node {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Property("tag")
    private String tag;
    @Relationship(type = "FROM", direction = OUTGOING)
    private Set<Node> outgoingNodes;
    @Relationship(type = "TO", direction = INCOMING)
    private Set<Node> incomingNodes;
    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public Set<Node> getOutgoingNodes() {
        return outgoingNodes;
    }
```

The NodeRepository class :

```
public interface NodeRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Node, String> {
    Optional<Node> findByTag(String tag);
}
```

And yet when I run the API I obtain this error :

`Failed to complete request: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.api.repositories.NodeRepository.findByTag(String)" because "this.nodeRepository" is null`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `@Autowired` annotation in controller methods isn't supported. You need to autowire them into the class itself. For example:

```java
@RestController
public class NodeController {
    @Autowired
    private SocialNetwork socialNetwork; // Add this

    @PostMapping("/metrics")
    // Remove the SocialNetwork parameter from computeMetrics()
    public MetricJSON computeMetrics( 
            @Valid @RequestBody MetricsPayload payload
    ) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new MetricJSON(socialNetwork.fromRequest(payload));
    }
}
```

(Preferably, you use construction injection in stead of field injection with `@Autowired`.)

The reason why you get this `NullPointerException` is because Spring will treat the `socialNetwork` parameter in your controller as a class where request attributes can be binded upon. This causes Spring to create a new instance of `SocialNetwork`, but not as a bean. So in this new instance of `SocialNetwork`, dependency injection won't happen.

Related: [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1915448)

Comment: This work ! Thank a lot. I'm new to spring and the controller was part of legacy code I received when I started working on it, so I erroneously belived it must has been working. Thanks again for you time

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) on a method parameter. It's not used by autowiring.

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

Instead create a property of controller and use it in the method

```
@RestController
public class NodeController {

   @Autowired SocialNetwork socialNetwork;

    @PostMapping("/metrics")
    public MetricJSON computeMetrics(
            @Valid @RequestBody MetricsPayload payload
            
    ) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new MetricJSON(socialNetwork.fromRequest(payload));
   }
}
```